# App Facebook login

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

I trying to make a login action for my Facebook App, the code is like this:

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function ()
    {
     FacebookLogin();

    });
```

....

```
function FacebookLogin()
    {

        FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {

            top.location.href = "result.html";
        } 
        }, {scope: 'email'});
    }
```

When I click on the login button, the Facebook login popup is showed and after the init session this pop up is not redirecting fine, is stopped in

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request..

I think that the problem is related to the settings security. If I disable the navigation security, the App is working fine, otherwise the "Login popup" is stopped in the url

Any idea?